# WallpaperService and Accelerometer

Tags: android, service, sensors, live-wallpaper

After trying everything I thought I will try to see if someone here knows what is my problem, before I give up completely. So what I am trying to do is to make my image slide behind this "rotating cube". For example if I tilt my phone to right it starts to slide right and vice versa.

Here is the code. It is very long and got much meaningless code for this question, but I thought to give it full, ignore the parts that arent importand. It is CubeWallpaper1 sample provided in sdk. I have just modified it and tried to add accelerometer to it and make it work.

So if you could take a look and tell me what is wrong with it.

```
public class LiveWall extends WallpaperService implements SensorEventListener {

    float xAxis,yAxis,zAxis;
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mAccelerometer;
    Bitmap drawable;


    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        drawable = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.bg);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

    }



    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        xAxis = event.values[0];
        yAxis = event.values[1];
        zAxis = event.values[2];
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public Engine onCreateEngine() {
        return new CubeEngine();
    }



    class CubeEngine extends Engine {

        private final Paint mPaint = new Paint();
        private float mOffset;
        private float mTouchX = -1;
        private float mTouchY = -1;
        private long mStartTime;
        private float mCenterX;
        private float mCenterY;

        private final Runnable mDrawCube = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                drawFrame();
            }
        };
        private boolean mVisible;

        CubeEngine() {
            // Create a Paint to draw the lines for our cube
            final Paint paint = mPaint;
            paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(15);
            paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

            mStartTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
            super.onCreate(surfaceHolder);

            // By default we don't get touch events, so enable them.
            setTouchEventsEnabled(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mDrawCube);
        }

        @Override
        public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible) {
            mVisible = visible;
            if (visible) {
                drawFrame();
            } else {
                mHandler.removeCallbacks(mDrawCube);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
            super.onSurfaceChanged(holder, format, width, height);
            // store the center of the surface, so we can draw the cube in the right spot
            mCenterX = width/2.0f;
            mCenterY = height/2.0f;
            drawFrame();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            super.onSurfaceCreated(holder);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            super.onSurfaceDestroyed(holder);
            mVisible = false;
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mDrawCube);
        }

        @Override
        public void onOffsetsChanged(float xOffset, float yOffset,
                float xStep, float yStep, int xPixels, int yPixels) {
            mOffset = xOffset;
            drawFrame();
        }

        /*
         * Store the position of the touch event so we can use it for drawing later
         */
        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                mTouchX = event.getX();
                mTouchY = event.getY();
            } else {
                mTouchX = -1;
                mTouchY = -1;
            }
            super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }

        /*
         * Draw one frame of the animation. This method gets called repeatedly
         * by posting a delayed Runnable. You can do any drawing you want in
         * here. This example draws a wireframe cube.
         */
        void drawFrame() {
            final SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();

            Canvas c = null;
            try {
                c = holder.lockCanvas();
                if (c != null) {
                    // draw something
                    drawCube(c);
                    drawTouchPoint(c);
                }
            } finally {
                if (c != null) holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }

            // Reschedule the next redraw
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mDrawCube);
            if (mVisible) {
                mHandler.postDelayed(mDrawCube, 1000 / 25);
            }
        }

        /*
         * Draw a wireframe cube by drawing 12 3 dimensional lines between
         * adjacent corners of the cube
         */
        void drawCube(Canvas c) {
            c.save();
            c.translate(mCenterX, mCenterY);
            c.drawColor(0xff000000);
            c.drawBitmap(drawable, 0+xAxis,0+yAxis, mPaint);
            drawLine(c, -400, -400, -400,  400, -400, -400);
            drawLine(c,  400, -400, -400,  400,  400, -400);
            drawLine(c,  400,  400, -400, -400,  400, -400);
            drawLine(c, -400,  400, -400, -400, -400, -400);

            drawLine(c, -400, -400,  400,  400, -400,  400);
            drawLine(c,  400, -400,  400,  400,  400,  400);
            drawLine(c,  400,  400,  400, -400,  400,  400);
            drawLine(c, -400,  400,  400, -400, -400,  400);

            drawLine(c, -400, -400,  400, -400, -400, -400);
            drawLine(c,  400, -400,  400,  400, -400, -400);
            drawLine(c,  400,  400,  400,  400,  400, -400);
            drawLine(c, -400,  400,  400, -400,  400, -400);
            c.restore();
        }

        /*
         * Draw a 3 dimensional line on to the screen
         */
        void drawLine(Canvas c, int x1, int y1, int z1, int x2, int y2, int z2) {
            long now = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
            float xrot = ((float)(now - mStartTime)) / 1000;
            float yrot = (0.5f - mOffset) * 2.0f;
            float zrot = 0;

            // 3D transformations

            // rotation around X-axis
            float newy1 = (float)(Math.sin(xrot) * z1 + Math.cos(xrot) * y1);
            float newy2 = (float)(Math.sin(xrot) * z2 + Math.cos(xrot) * y2);
            float newz1 = (float)(Math.cos(xrot) * z1 - Math.sin(xrot) * y1);
            float newz2 = (float)(Math.cos(xrot) * z2 - Math.sin(xrot) * y2);

            // rotation around Y-axis
            float newx1 = (float)(Math.sin(yrot) * newz1 + Math.cos(yrot) * x1);
            float newx2 = (float)(Math.sin(yrot) * newz2 + Math.cos(yrot) * x2);
            newz1 = (float)(Math.cos(yrot) * newz1 - Math.sin(yrot) * x1);
            newz2 = (float)(Math.cos(yrot) * newz2 - Math.sin(yrot) * x2);

            // 3D-to-2D projection
            float startX = newx1 / (4 - newz1 / 400);
            float startY = newy1 / (4 - newz1 / 400);
            float stopX =  newx2 / (4 - newz2 / 400);
            float stopY =  newy2 / (4 - newz2 / 400);

            c.drawLine(startX, startY, stopX, stopY, mPaint);
        }

        /*
         * Draw a circle around the current touch point, if any.
         */
        void drawTouchPoint(Canvas c) {
            if (mTouchX >=0 && mTouchY >= 0) {
                c.drawCircle(mTouchX, mTouchY, 80, mPaint);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only must you implement `SensorEventListener` but you also have to register the listener (your Activity in this case) with the `SensorManager`.

In your `onStart` method do this:

```
SensorManager sensorMgr = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
sensorMgr.registerListener(this, sensorMgr.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

In `onStop` (or `onPause`) don't forget to unregister:

```
SensorManager sensorMgr = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
sensorMgr.unregisterListener(this, sensorMgr.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER));
```

You also might read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html) of `SensorManager` with has some good examples too.

Comment: I still cant get it work, i updated my code if you could have a look. What I am trying to do is get my drawable to move right and left on the screen based on accelerometer values. I am aware that this way i wont be able to get it move more than around 9.8 but that is what i want for now. I just want to see my code working for now

Comment: c.drawBitmap(drawable, 0+xAxis,0+yAxis, mPaint);  this is the code that I am using to draw my image

Comment: What do you get at all? Is the drawable rendered at all and just doesn't move? Try to log the x,y,z values in onSensorChanged() to see if it is called and what values you get.

Comment: Also perhaps you should put your c.drawBitmap _before_ the c.save(), because they use this and the following c.translate() to draw the cube at the center of the canvas.

Comment: Image is drawn in the center but doesnt move. ok ill try to change those now

Comment: ok now that i put drawBitmap before c.save, it disappered totally

Comment: Ok, by putting c.drawBitmap before c.save() it should at least be drawn at the top-left corner :-) If it does not move, you do not get values for x,y,z axis obviously (or you do not move your phone)

Comment: its not drawn at all if i put it before c.save();

Comment: it is drawn only if set after c.drawColor(0xff000000);

Comment: OK. Probably it's invisible otherwise (0xff000000 sets opacity to full). But your main problem is to move the bitmap, right? So try to log the x,y,z values in onSensorChanged() to see if it is called at all...

Comment: i just tried logging them and yes they do change according to logcat. so I cant understand what am I doing wrong now?

Comment: Ohh i got it work. The value 9.* was so small that i could barely notice that it is moving. thanks!

Comment: I will award my bounty to you as soon as it will be availble.

Comment: One more thing:P do you know why movement of picture isnt smooth?

Comment: Yeah, I thought that this will come up :) This is because the sensor's measures aren't very exact. You should apply a low-pass filter to the values you get. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html for an example.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting accelerometer data in Wallpaper Service. Here is my code:

```
public class MyWallpaperService extends WallpaperService {

Context context;

public void onCreate() {
    context = this;
    super.onCreate();
}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

public Engine onCreateEngine() {
    return new MyWallpaperEngine();
}

class MyWallpaperEngine extends Engine implements SensorEventListener {

    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    private final Runnable drawRunner = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            draw();
        }
    };
    private boolean visible = true;

    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mAccelerometer;
    private Display mDisplay;

    private Bitmap mBackground;

    private float mSensorX;
    private float mSensorY;
    private float mSensorZ;

    MyWallpaperEngine() {

        mBackground = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.background);

        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        WindowManager mWindowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        mDisplay = mWindowManager.getDefaultDisplay();

        BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opts.inDither = true;
        opts.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
        mBackground = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.grass, opts);
    }

    public void registerSensors() {
        Log.d(TAG, "registerSensors()");
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
    }

    public void unregisterSensors() {
        Log.d(TAG, "unregisterSensors()");
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }

    @Override
     public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (event.sensor.getType() != Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
            return;

        switch (mDisplay.getRotation()) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                mSensorX = event.values[0];
                mSensorY = event.values[1];
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                mSensorX = -event.values[1];
                mSensorY = event.values[0];
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                mSensorX = -event.values[0];
                mSensorY = -event.values[1];
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                mSensorX = event.values[1];
                mSensorY = -event.values[0];
                break;
        }
        mSensorZ = event.values[2];
        //This is your Accelerometer X,Y,Z values
        Log.d(TAG, "X: " + mSensorX + ", Y: " + mSensorY + ", Z: " + mSensorZ);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }


    public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        super.onCreate(surfaceHolder);
        registerSensors();
    }

    @Override
    public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible) {
        this.visible = visible;
        // if screen wallpaper is visible then draw the image otherwise do not draw
        if (visible) {
            handler.post(drawRunner);
        } else {
            handler.removeCallbacks(drawRunner);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        super.onSurfaceDestroyed(holder);
        this.visible = false;
        handler.removeCallbacks(drawRunner);
    }

    public void onOffsetsChanged(float xOffset, float yOffset, float xStep, float yStep, int xPixels, int yPixels) {
        final SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();


            draw();
    }

    void draw() {
        final SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();

        Canvas c = null;
        try {
            c = holder.lockCanvas();
            // clear the canvas
            c.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

            if (c != null) {
                c.drawBitmap(mBackground, 0, 0, null);

            }
        }
        finally {
            if (c != null)
                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
        }

        handler.removeCallbacks(drawRunner);
        if (visible) {
            handler.postDelayed(drawRunner, 10); // delay 10 mileseconds
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        unregisterSensors();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

}